# Why is my simulator display a black screen after running my project?

Tags: ios, xcode

When i hit run (the play button) in xcode, the simulator runs and displays a black screen. I have to hit stop to make it run my application. Anyone else got this weird bug? The application that i'm running is just the starting project of single view application template. I'm using Xcode 5.1. Could anyone help me please? thanks

Comment: restart and run again

Comment: Xcode latest version is 5.1 !

Comment: I have tried restarting xcode and restart my laptop. But doesn't seem to work

Comment: Can you share your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` this method from AppDelegate?

Comment: hi @Rashadm here is my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 

`(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
})`

Comment: sorry the code looks nasty